# Is it possible to automatically aggregate / collect test results from different projects using Serenity BDD?

Tags: metrics, test-report, serenity-bdd

I use Serenity BDD in multiple maven projects. I would like to collect basic information (number of passed and failed cases, time of execution) from all project into one place - one HTML, CSV file, database or email.
Is it possible to do that automatically? Do I need any additional tool?

Answer (score 0):

Serenity BDD [generates reports in XML](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_loading_test_outcomes_from_folder), which allows you to parse programmatically any data you want from them.